# How to validate multiple attachments upload size?

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload, carrierwave

Hi I'm using carrierwave for uploading multiple files using its [array approach](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#multiple-file-uploads), but couldn't figure out how to validate the size of uploaded multiple files. I thought about something like this:

```
post.attachments.each do |a|
puts a.size.to_i
end
```

and then somehow sum it up and write a validation for the total size. Or it can also be performed on individual level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I finally found the answer. First I create array of sizes, then sum it up and validate total size:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
validate :attachments_size

 private
  def attachments_size
    size_array = self.attachments.collect { |e| e.size }
    if size_array.inject(0, :+) > 2.megabytes
      errors.add(:attachments, "should be less than 2MB")
    end
  end
```